# Login page is not redirecting properly to the user according to their level

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have code and it gives the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: user_level in C:\xampp\htdocs\user personal\components\login-process.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined variable: user_level in C:\xampp\htdocs\user personal\components\login-process.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined variable: user_level in C:\xampp\htdocs\user personal\components\login-process.php on line 37
```

user_level is in my db and i dont seem to know what to do here

here is the code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_REQUEST['login_button'])||$_REQUEST['auto']==1){
        require '../_database/database.php';
        $errmsg_arr = array();
        $errflag = false;
        $username=  mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$_REQUEST['username']);
        $password=  mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$_REQUEST['password']);
        if($username == '') {
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
            $errflag = true;
        }
        if($password == '') {
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
            $errflag = true;
        }
        if($errflag) {
            $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
            session_write_close();
            header("location: authentication-check.php");
            exit();
        }
        $sql="SELECT user_username,user_password FROM user WHERE user_username='$username'AND user_password='$password'";
        $result=  mysqli_query($database,$sql) or die(mysqli_errno());
        $trws= mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($trws==1){
            $rws=  mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $_SESSION['user_username']=$rws['user_username'];
            $_SESSION['user_password']=$rws['user_password'];
              $_SESSION['user_level'] =$rws['user_level'];
            if($user_level == "1"){
            //to admin home
           header("Location: ../files/A-HOMEPAGE.php");
            exit();
            }
            //to user home
            elseif($user_level == "2"){
            header("Location: ../user/A-HOMEPAGE.php");
            exit();
            }    
        }
        else {
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'user name and password not found';
            $errflag = true;
            if($errflag) {
                $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
                session_write_close();
                header("location: ../components/authentication-check.php");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Like the errors say, the `$user_level` variable hasn't been defined yet. You're checking the value of `$user_level` in an if statement before defining what it is. Perhaps you want to set `$user_level = $_SESSION['user_level']`?

Comment: I have tried the solution you just gave out, the error has gone away but then it brings out a blank page with the address of the login page.so the redirect to the given pages is not working.what should i do here!!? thanks